# c++ performance improvement for a simple function

Tags: c++, performance

I have a function in my program that gets called many many times. It is not particularly slow, it is just that it gets called so many times that any little improvement can help a lot.

```
inline static void addFanVertex(GLfloat x,GLfloat y, GLfloat r, GLfloat g, GLfloat b) {
            tf.push_back(x);
            tf.push_back(y);
            tf.push_back(r);
            tf.push_back(g);
            tf.push_back(b);
            tfe.push_back((tf.size()/5)-1);
        }
```

tf and tfe are vectors:

```
std::vector<GLfloat> Renderer::tf;
std::vector<GLuint> Renderer::tfe;
```

I use std::reserve already to set their correct capacity. (Doesn't have significant performance improvements)

Anyone know something that would speed it up slightly?

Comment: I think that you can improve it a lot by reserving the required number of entries in advance (if you do, then please show it in your code, so we can be sure that you are doing it correctly).

Comment: @barakmanos I do that already with tf.reserve(newCapacity). With that the capacity is never increased when calling push_back, yet I didn't notice any performance increase in the profiler. Probably because copying floats is pretty fast?

Comment: Your profiler should be able to provide some hints regarding whether any micro-optimisation here is worthwhile, but I don't think there's much you can do about it. (Side note: the most effective optimisation would be to call this function less often, of course.)

Comment: The only thing I would consider testing would be `tf.insert(tf.end(), {x, y, r, g, b});`, but I am pretty sure it won't increase the performance.

Comment: @macco: I honestly believe that it could prove useful if you added this to the code in your question.

Comment: Another side note: it's possible that your modifying both vectors here is causing cache problems. Try building them separately and see if that helps.

Comment: @nelxiost That actually makes it twice as slow.

Comment: I doubt it will change much in this case, but try `emplace_back()` rather than `push_back()` - worth a shot. Also make sure you are compiling with optimization enabled (aka release mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no so many thing to do about your function. A little bit context could help in this case.

For example it could be no necessary push values in the vector in each cycle, or maybe the `operator[]` could be used.

Anyway just seeing that, I'd say to try something like:

1. Check in disassemble whether the arguments are passed by stack allocation or by registers (it depend on the compiler). In case of stack you could "compress" your arguments in a `struct` and pass just that argument to the function. Moreover that struct should be pre-allocated with a `static` or a member function in the *caller*.
2. You could think to use `noexcept` specifier (in case your compiler support it). That may enable some optimized compiler's operations. This in accordance with the fact the resources are pre-allocated correctly in the program and you trust that code.
3. Use an profiler to see which micro-operations (also assembly lines) are the bottleneck of the function.